What is the most compact way to describe matrix diagonal vector?
If I describe a matrix as:
$\Sigma_t \simeq \text{diag}\left({s^2_{t,1}}, {s^2_{t,2}}, \dots, {s^2_{t,K}} \right) =
\begin{bmatrix}
       {s^2_{t,1}} &  &  & \\
       & {s^2_{t,2}} &  &  \\
       &  & \ddots &       \\
       &  &  & {s^2_{t,K}}
\end{bmatrix}
$
what would be the most compact notation to describe the vector $s_t\in\mathbb{R}^K$ aggregating all $K$ diagonal elements $s^2_{t,k}$, without explicitly writing
$s_t=[s^2_{t,1} s^2_{t,2} \dotsb s^2_{t,K}]$?
Using $s^2_t=\operatorname{diag}(\Sigma_t)$ would be ambigous (apparently $\operatorname{diag}$ is used in both contexts), and I'm not sure if $s^2_t=[s^2_{t,k}],~\forall k\in\{1,2,\dots,K\}$ is entirely correct.

diag is not ambiguous: it means one thing when the input is a matrix and another when the input is a vector.

maybe not in the strict sense, but using the same operator under two different contexts in the same paragraph is bound to cause confusion on readers, if said readers aren't aware of that distinction
